# retrieve data dynamically from several json array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

i get several json array and i want to retrieve some data in a loop. what i want is the value of the key `count`

Here is my code :

```
                .then(function(){
                    var tabuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myid"));

                    for(i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++){
                        console.log(tabuser[i].id);
                        displayfilter
                            .user(token,tabuser[i].id)
                            .then(function(data){

                                console.log(data);
                                $scope.numtickets = data;


                            })
                    }

                })
```

Here what i get from my `console.log(data):

[image]

And i want to retrieve the value of the key `count`for every json array. How can i display that in my view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a json array:

```
$scope.numtickets = [];
```

Keep pushing the value of the keycount:

```
$scope.numtickets.push(data);
```

Display the array on the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="numticket in numtickets">
   {{numticket.count}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is a really good start but it only display the value 'count' of the last array and not every array. I think i have to push the value of 'count' in a new array and then retrieve them easily. Because your method give me several  different tab which contain the key 'count' if you see what i mean.

Comment: Try using: `$scope.numtickets.push(angular.copy(data))`

Comment: it copy only the last value so it's the same result as before :(

Comment: Try this:        
 `.then(function(){
      var tabuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myid"));

        $q.all($scope.tabuser.map(function(obj) {
          return displayfilter.user(token,obj.id)
        })).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.numtickets = data;
        });
  });`

Comment: i manage it, what i did is just to declare '$scope.numtickets = [];' outside the loop